# Array in Classes C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am really new to C# and I am currently working on an assignment that doesnt really make sense to me. I need a kick in the right direction.

The assignment:

I need to make a console Application which is called grocerylist. This grocery list contains a class named GroceryList. This class contains an instance variable products which is an array.

The array contains items of the type product.

the class product has a string name and int quantity as attributes. The product class is abstract, and has 2 sub classes called fresh and herbs.

I need to show that I can add items to the GroceryList and display the list.

The problem I have is that the array is in the class GroceryList and I cannot add products to it. I am missing something, I have been pondering for weeks what it could be and tried different solutions without result. I am even wondering if the assignment is wrong. This is what I have so far:

```
namespace GroceryList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool Displaymenu = true;
            while (Displaymenu == true)
            {
                Displaymenu = mainMenu();
            }


        }
        public bool mainMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("1) add a fresh product");
            Console.WriteLine("2) add a herb");
            Console.WriteLine("3) exit");

            string result = Console.ReadLine();

            if (result == "1");
            {
                Console.Clear();
                product.fresh fresh1 = new product.fresh();
                Console.WriteLine("What type of fresh product would you like to add?");
                fresh1.naam = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("How much of " + fresh1.naam + " would you like to add?");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                int quant;
                int.TryParse(number, out quant);
                fresh1.Quantity = quant;



                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    public class GroceryList
    {
        List<product> products = new List<product>();

    }
    abstract class product
    {
        public string naam { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public class fresh : product
        {

        }
        public class herbs : product
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your access modifiers are off. You said it yourself, `The problem I have is that the array is in the class GroceryList and I cannot add products to it`. So make it so you can by reading about access modifiers ;)

Comment: You need to explicitly mark your List as public in GroceryList. In C#, properties are marked as private by default if you do not put an access modifier on them.

Answer (score 1):

The `GroceryList` class that you created needs to be instantiated (declared) in your code so that you can use the `List<product>` inside of it. Exactly as you declared `fresh1` as a `product.fresh` object, you must declare an object as a `GroceryList`.

So, you can declare `GroceryList list = new GroceryList()` at the beginning of your code. Then, you will want to add items to the `products` field of your `GroceryList list`.

There are two ways to do this. One way is to directly access the `list` object inside of the class.

To do this, you need to make your `list` field `public` so that it can be accessed from outside the object. To declare it as public, put a `public` keyword infront of the field declaration.

This isn't necessarily the best practice of doing this, as for a function like adding, it's better to have a clear `method` that does actions like this on fields instead of modifying them directly from outside of the object (if you want to learn more about this idea, it's called [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).) A useful method that you could use for this program would be a `AddProduct` method.

Now, what do we need this method to do? Add a `product` object to the `list` that we have inside of our `GroceryList`.

So, we need to declare the method inside of the `GroceryList` object as follows.

```
public void AddProduct(product productToAdd)
{
    products.Add(productToAdd);
}
```

Then, when you want to add a product to the `GroceryList` object, you would call `AddProduct(productVariableHere)` on the `list` object that you create.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your GroceryList class have ***property*** of products.

```
public class GroceryList
{
    public GroceryList()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then adding products might look like

```
var bananas = new Product {Name = "banana", Quantity = 2};
var list = new GroceryList();
list.Products.Add(bananas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated you are learning the language:

1. You may want to consider adding an `Add()` method on the `GroceryList` class.
2. Exposing the list as public is not a sound design because someone can set that to null or delete items etc.
3. In very specific scenarios where you need to expose it, you can use `ReadOnlyCollection`.